How to config Spring Security requestMatchers() in case has path variable(s)?
I am using Spring Boot 3.4.0 , Spring Security 6.5.1, Spring Web, Java 23.
Case 1
.requestMatchers(GET, "/foo/{foo_id}/bars").hasAnyRole(SUPER_HERO.name(), KNIGHT.name())

Case 2
.requestMatchers(POST, "/foo/{foo_id}/baas/{bar_id}").hasAnyRole(SUPER_HERO.name())

How to config Spring Security requestMatchers() in case has path variable(s)?

You mean:
.requestMatchers(GET, "/foo/*/bars").hasAnyRole(SUPER_HERO.name(), KNIGHT.name()) .requestMatchers(POST, "/foo/*/baas/*").hasAnyRole(SUPER_HERO.name())

I avoid case .requestMatchers(GET, "/foo/{abc}/{xyz}/bars") . Have you any idea?

This seems like it might be a duplicate of 70391195. Does that answer your question?

A part of the question is the same (URL path with parameter(s)), another path is different (Java 23, Spring Security 6.4.0, Spring Boot 3.4.0, RESTful API). @SteveRiesenberg , should I use .requestMatchers(POST, "/foo/{foo_id}/baas/{bar_id}").hasAnyRole(SUPER_HERO.name()) . Your idea is authoritative voice, you can help me an answer.

Sorry @VyDo, I fail to see how Java 23 or recent versions of Spring Security significantly change the question. "should I use .requestMatchers(POST, "/foo/{foo_id}/baas/{bar_id}").hasAnyRole(SUPER_HERO.name()). " I don't understand the question. Are you receiving an error? What would you like to do with the path variables? Please add more clarity to the question so I understand what exactly you're asking and I will be happy to provide an answer if it's different from the question I linked.

have you tried ?
.requestMatchers(POST, "/foo/*/baas/*").hasAnyRole(SUPER_HERO.name())

I will follow your idea, if we cannot find a more strict way. I think it will works as expected, because /*/ and /**/ are different. If you find any reference document link, I will be more confident.
